# UISlider setMaximumTrackTintColor doesn't work in IB

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uislider

I have a `UISlider` in my window and I can't change its `setMaximumTrackTintColor` in Interface Builder. I set this color to one that I need, and Interface Builder's preview is ok, but on both the simulator and device this color is always `RGB 183,183,183`. Also, changing this value in code works good, but that behaviour is like magic for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a bug in interface builder. I'm using Xcode 6.3.1 and was able to reproduce this as well. Min Track Tint and Thumb Tint work, but Max Track Tint has no effect when running on device.